# TRIM() function in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Using Kibana 5.5.2.  I have 18 million records in an index called 'suppliers'.  What I'm trying to do with the code below is to trim all leading/trailing white space, but I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> "type": "parse_exception",
> "reason": "expected one of [inline], [file] or [stored] fields, but found none"
> ```

Here is the code I'm using.  '`name`' is the field I'm trying to trim on all 18M documents in the index:

```
POST suppliers/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.name=trim(name)",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Please help

Comment: As you are trying to change the source of the docs, can you tell me how your docs are stored? Do you have the _source stored in the index too?

Comment: Hi @ibexit.  I'm too new to ESS to answer your question, but here's my shot.  When looking in Kibana at a single record/document, looking at the json I see:

Comment: {
  "_index": "suppliers",
  "_type": "supplier",
  "_id": "AWXTz-w97Ruksbf7XWeT",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "name": "ABC COMPANY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "
  }
}

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to define an ingest pipeline with a [`trim` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/trim-processor.html) and then use it in your Update by query call.

First define your pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/trim
{
  "description" : "trims my name field",
  "processors" : [ {
      "trim" : {
        "field": "name"
      }
  } ]
}
```

Then specify it when calling update by query:

```
POST suppliers/_update_by_query?pipeline=trim
```

Comment: Val...thanks so much for getting back to me.  Question...will this work on the 18M documents that I already have in ESS?  I thought that ingest pipelines are used only when loading (i.e. ingesting) data into ESS??

Comment: Actually @Val, looks like I might have gotten a little further.  Here is the code I executed:  PUT _ingest/pipeline/trim
{
  "description" : "trims my name field",
  "processors" : [ {
      "trim" : {
        "field": "name"
      }
  } ]
}

POST suppliers/_update_by_query?pipeline=trim

Comment: and here are the results.  what to do next?

Comment: # PUT _ingest/pipeline/trim
{
  "acknowledged": true
}

# POST suppliers/_update_by_query?pipeline=trim
{
  "took": 1601,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 18867459,
  "updated": 0,
  "deleted": 0,
  "batches": 1,
  "version_conflicts": 1000,
  "noops": 0,
  "retries": {
    "bulk": 0,
    "search": 0
  },
  "throttled_millis": 0,
  "requests_per_second": -1,
  "throttled_until_millis": 0,
  "failures": [
    {
      "index": "suppliers",
      "type": "supplier",

Comment: "id": "AWXTx7y142zIRdYuCwuf",
      "cause": {
        "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
        "reason": "[supplier][AWXTx7y142zIRdYuCwuf]: version conflict, current version [2] is different than the one provided [1]",
        "index_uuid": "u2ivcMRDQcmKxpRjuqAytA",
        "shard": "1",
        "index": "suppliers"
      },
      "status": 409
    }

Answer (score 0):

@Val and @ibexit.  thanks for your help.  Val's response worked...I just had it formatted incorrectly the first time.  here is what worked:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/trim
{
  "description" : "trims my name field",
  "processors" : [ {
      "trim" : {
        "field": "name"
      }
  } ]
}
POST suppliers/_update_by_query?pipeline=trim
```

Comment: Hey @Brad, please consider voting up Val answer/comment helped you - cheers! BTW: consider splitting your update to multiple threads in order to increase the speed of your trim job.